# How do I create my own syntax / rewrite existing syntax in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Here is, for example, a standard `if` semantic:

```
if (condition)
     do stuff
end
```

What I want to be able to do is to re-write `if` in such a way that, if an exception is thrown, I can do some error handling.

Does ruby have a way to re-define pre-existing syntax? If so, how?

EDIT:
Lets say in an if condition, a method is called on nil in the condition `if(my_object.my_method)`.  If `my_object` isn't defined, ruby would throw an error.  I'd like to be able to change the way if behaves such that it can catch errors. (In my specific situation, it would email me the stack trace... but emailing is the easy part).

Comment: Can you post here your case of what exectly you want to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's need to redefine the ruby behavior.

For sure your application has kinda main method, so you can wrapp it with exception handling.

```
begin  
   # main method  
rescue => msg  # by default it will catch only StandartError
   # send email "hi, you have a problem in you application"  
end
```

Comment: this will work for sending email, but lets say, I want to return a default value? 

I wonder if ruby 2.0 will allow syntax rewriting.

apparently ruby syntax can't be re-written. =D

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way is to wrap your script with exception handling, which I'd bet could be done without mich effort by working with load or require. Otherwise you're talking about either (a) rewriting how Ruby works, or (b) modifying the AST at load time.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the syntax or semantics of Ruby in a Ruby program. You may want to use Perl6 or a Lisp instead.